# Pip install alternatives

Tags: pip, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to install the [dawdreamer](https://github.com/DBraun/DawDreamer) package onto my Raspberry Pi (running the latest Raspbian OS and my python version is 3.9.2). However, the problem  is that dawdreamer wasn't built for Raspberry Pi.

So, when I tried `pip install dawdreamer`, I got this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirements dawdreamer
ERROR: No matching distribution found for dawdreamer
```

Then I tried `pip install "git+https://github.com/DBraun/DawDreamer.git"`, but when it started getting the requirements to build wheel, I got:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1
...
AssertionError: File not found: /tmp/pip-req-build-xxxxxxx/dawdreamer/dawdreamer.so
```

Then after doing that, I cloned the dawdreamer repo and tried `pip install -e DawDreamer/`. But, when it starting getting the requirements to build wheel, I got the following error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with the exit status 1
...
AssertionError: File not found: /home/jackphilips/dawdreamer/dawdreamer.so
```

Is it just not possible to install dawdreamer onto my Raspberry Pi until the package is built for it? Or could I try something else? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried something like `python3 -m pip install <pkg>` or `pip3 install <pkg>`
what python version are you using ?

Comment: @Schwenk I've tried both commands but I get the same error as when I do ```pip install dawdreamer```. And I've added the python version to the op (3.9.3).